# Spring 4 Migrate from hibernate 4 to 5 session return null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

After upgrading libs version to last and refreshing configurations session start giving null objects.
I tried with different configurations, but this may be better from all.
Could you help and explain what happened with upgrade?

```
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>  




        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.project"});
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

            return sessionFactory;
        }


        @Bean
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
            return txManager;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource restDataSource() {
            final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"),
                    env.getProperty("jdbc.user"), env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
            return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
        }

        final Properties hibernateProperties() {
            return new Properties() {
                {
                    setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                    setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
                    setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext");
                    setProperty("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy","org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl");
                    setProperty("hibernate.format_sql","false");
                    setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments","false");
                    setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings","true");
                    setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans","true");
                    setProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth","1");
                    setProperty("hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size","16");

                }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your import of `LocalSessionFactoryBean` is of hibernate 5

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

Comment: Thx for answer, my imports was of  5 versions, and it's not solved the problem(

Comment: @BabyGluk do you see any exceptions in your console

Comment: It's interesting, that i haven't any exceptions in logs. i gettings session from sessionFactory and get object from by criteria, on result i have null, but when i revert configs and pom all work fine on old versions